# Change color of cell if value is < or > to another table cell value - Only applies to first row

Tags: javascript, php

I am not very good at coding i hope someone can help me out.

I am trying to create a basic program where i select values form a mysql table via array into table cells and change colours of those cells if < or > compared to another cell value. I have got everything working but i am stuck with this. When the code runs it only applys the script/css where it changes color to the first row only and it does not apply to the rest of the row cells. I have cut down on my code to only show the issue i am facing so this code below is only a snippets of my code to give an idea so parts of it may be incomplete.

Basically the color changes only applies to the first row does not apply to other rows

Can anyone point me in the right direction to sort this issue

```
<?php
include_once 'temp/dbconnect.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM cusers WHERE email='".$_SESSION['_email']."' ORDER BY id DESC");



?>
 <?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
?>

<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

?>
```

```
<?PHP 
$num_of_alerts_achived1=($row["num_of_alerts_achived"]);
$num_of_alerts_achived1_res = (int)$num_of_alerts_achived1;
?>


<?PHP 
$alert_count_eng2= ($row["total_global_alert_count"]) / ($row["engineer_count"]);
$alert_count_per_eng2_res=$alert_count_eng2*1.3;
$alert_count_per_eng2_res = (int)$alert_count_per_eng2_res;
?>


<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-tvyx" colspan="3">No of Alerts(25%)</td>
        <td class="tg-xcv"><?php echo $num_of_alerts_achived1_res; ?></td>
        <td class="tg-xcv"><?php echo $alert_count_per_eng1_res; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size:10px;" class="alert-t1-overwrite"><?php echo $alert_count_per_eng1_res; ?></td>
        <td class="tg-xcv"><?php echo $alert_count_per_eng2_res; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size:10px;" class="alert-t2-overwrite"><?php echo $alert_count_per_eng2_res; ?></td>
      
    
      </tr>
 </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            
            $('.alert-t1-overwrite').each(function() {
                if(parseInt($(this).text(), 10) <= <?php echo $num_of_alerts_achived1_res;  ?>) {
                    $(this).addClass('alert-t1_overwritten');
                }
            });
            
            $('.alert-t2-overwrite').each(function() {
                if(parseInt($(this).text(), 10) <= <?php echo $num_of_alerts_achived1_res; ?> ) {
                    $(this).addClass('alert-t2_overwritten');
                }
            });
            
        
        </script>


.alert-t1-overwrite {color:red;background-color: red; text-align:center; }
.alert-t1_overwritten {color:green;background-color: green; text-align:center;}



.alert-t2-overwrite {color:red;background-color: red; text-align:center; }
.alert-t2_overwritten {color:green;background-color: green; text-align:center;}
```

[Front end test 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYr4V.png)

[Front end test 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHC40.png)

Comment: Your CSS should be in a style block inside the head section.  Or an external style sheet.  Don't do jQuery so I can't help there.

Comment: Why wouldn't you set this while you're building the table HTML? There's no need to involve jQuery after the page has loaded, that's unnecessary and overcomplicated